# help with array

Tags: c++, arrays

> You will write a program that
>   evaluates the integral of sin(x) using
>   the left-hand rectangle rule with 2000
>   subintervals, over 10 intervals. The
>   intervals to test are [0, 1), [1, 2),
>   …, [8, 9), [9, 10). You will declare
>   an array of type double that can hold
>   10 elements, and you will use this
>   array to hold all 10 results you get
>   from evaluating each interval.

I am in testing my code, what should be the output?
For example, [0, 1)? Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably homework? You should identify homework as such.

Comment: Yes. It is a homework. But I just need some real output to test it out. Thanks.

Comment: It helps to first think what the output looks like before writing the program. Call me crazy.

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site, not a calculus one. Besides, calculus is so easy...

Comment: @Eduardo, the trouble is that MthOverflow.net is full of elitists.

Comment: @Hamish: Uh no. They aren't elitists, they're actually quite nice. **MathOverflow.net is for post-graduate level questions only.** If you don't fit that bill, don't post there. It's that simple.

Comment: No. I need help with the number output because different people are giving me different answer. But according to my knowledge, this integral is just 1- cos(1) for [0,1). some people get weird numbers.

Comment: @GMan, do you know if there is an equivalent stack exchange-based site for undergraduate level math?

Comment: @Hamish: I don't, sorry. I think the MO faq has some links though.

Comment: @Hamish: I don't know either. However, undergraduate math is reasonably understandable if you read the right books. I learnt calculus from the Leithold book when I was in my next-to-last year of high school (US equivalent: junior), and, believe me, once you get past limits, it's all easy. Limits are hard to grasp, though, since their formal symbolic definition (epsilon-delta) must be related to their geometric meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a `sin` function you should be able to figure it out. For more complicated cases use this tool:

http://calc.matthen.com/

http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp

Comment: Thank you Hamish for your help. I think I got verification from some other people too. So my classmates were all wrong with the area.
Thanks. I just need to confirm on the output. even if i have perfect codes, only knowing the real solutions can verify the code. Thanks

Comment: Haha! The brutal reality ... do not mess with machines, says Kasparov.

Comment: @JohnWong: Actually, a numerical integration algorithm won't return the very exact answer but for some trivial cases that don't require numerical integration algorithms anyway. Given bad input (for example, bad intervals), numerical algorithms can return bogus answers.

Comment: @ edurado, yes. i noticed that my answers were off by 0.0001 - 0.0002 but it was totally acceptable as you mention. thanks bro